# Keep getting error while retrieving SqlGeography field

Tags: c#, sql-server

Running this code:

```
(new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand($"select top 0 * from GeoTable", conn))).FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

on two different machines and still getting

```
Unknown error: DataReader.GetFieldType(0) returned null.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)
```

on one of them.

The `GeoTable` contain one field of `SqlGeography` type. Both PCs have references to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` of same version. Both can create a DataTable with a column of SqlGeography type. But when trying to *retrieve* schema from table containing SqlGeography one machine gives an error.

Both machines have same Visual Studio, SqlClient and Sql Server versions. What is left to check?

Comment: the data is the same on both?

Comment: @Izikon table is empty, I only retrieve schema

Comment: why using `SchemaType.Mapped` and not SchemaType.Source`?